# Delete null items from a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page which queries a database and and stores the results in a mapped array dictionary type. the issue im having is that some of the "rows" in the results are null, so I might have 20 records returned and the first three might be null

so I am going through each individual array and checking if that is null, so my questions is how do I delete this from the collection of array.

if I do something like

```
Objects[i].Remove(Objects[i].Keys.ToString());
```

I get an error because Objects[i] is null

Comment: It's unclear what you're really trying to do, what the types involved are etc. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and clarify your question. Note that calling `Dictionary<,>.Keys.ToString()` is rarely going to do what you want...

Comment: Can't you prevent building an array with nulls in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to solve the problem. Assuming you are working with a Dictionary:

```
//Sample data, this dictionary is the one you get from the query to the database
Dictionary Objects= new Dictionary()
{
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => null,
    "key3" => "value3"
};

//This will contain the same data as Objects but without the null values
Dictionary Objects2 = (from kv in Objects
    where kv.Value != null
    select kv).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate/loop over collection from the back (its last item towards first). Check for null, delete appropriately. General construct:

```
for(int n = collection.length; n >= 0; n--)
{
    if(collection[n] == null)
    {
        // delete collection[n]
    }
}
```

Comment: First, yes, you can (it's related to something called array re-initializing and can be encapsulated to be transparent to your smart eyes). Second, the question wasn't strictly about arrays; it was more like about collections in general - I quote: "mapped array dictionary type". And, third, I labeled my code snippet as "general construct" - how much more warnings about "this is a general approach to your general problem" do you want...

Comment: The OP talks about an array. Removing items from an array (itself) is not supported. Downvoting is normal practice, nothing to get snappy about.

Comment: Half of the questions here are "give me the copy-paste solution, so that I can paste it in my project without doing any thinking, whatsoever". I'm not saying this question is like that, but expecting copy-paste answers is simply too much. Mine [answer], in particular, was to give a direction of how to go about it, which I think I did, at least "kinda".